# How To Properly "Order By" This Arg

Tags: php

The following argument works properly for search results, however they aren't displaying in the proper ascending order. I'm looking to display the most expensive at the top, and so on.

Here's my code, where the $input_price is user defined by preset values within a form.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'post',
    's' => $query,
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'cat' => "$category_name",
    'meta_query'        => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'price',
            'value' => "$input_price",
            'type' => 'numeric',
            'compare' => '<=',
        'order' => 'ASC'
        )
    )
    );
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
```

I don't think this is the problem, but the 'price' is being output with currency and comma values, as seen below.

```
<?php $meta = get_post_custom($post->ID);
echo '$'.number_format($meta['price'][0], 0, '.', ',').''; ?>
```

Annnd here's the loop to display

```
<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

<h1><?php the_title() ;?></h1>  
<?php $meta = get_post_custom($post->ID);
echo '$'.number_format($meta['price'][0], 0, '.', ',').''; ?>   
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>

<?php endwhile; else: ?>

<p>Sorry, there are no products within those search terms! Try Adjusting the maximum price.</p>
```

Thanks!

Comment: How do you sort them?

Comment: Updated the original question, is that what you were looking for?

Comment: You are saying the order is wrong. To answer that you have to show how you sort them. The update you show doesn't show how you sort them. If you are not sorting them that is the problem

Comment: Newer to php, I thought 'order' => 'ASC' would sort the results.. How would I go about sorting results? (I'll start googling)

Comment: You are right. What is the order you get? Could it be that price are strings and get compared as string and not numbers

Comment: This is all a test, I currently have 4 'price' meta keys as follows (69, 10, 149, 99). They are also displaying in that order from top to bottom.

I could very well be saving them as a string on accident. I'll look into it and see!

Comment: which is the order you get?

Comment: Current order is showing as follows, from top to bottom (1 being top, 4 being the bottom). 1-69, 2-10, 3-149, 4-99.

Answer (score 0):

try DESC instead of ASC for greatest to smallest?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer!

The code below works as intended. I re-ordered my array slightly to include 'orderby' at the very end, while also specifying which key to order by.

```
<?php 


$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'post',
's' => $query,
'post_status' => 'publish',
'cat' => "$category_name",
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'price',
        'value' => "$input_price",
        'type' => 'numeric',
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'compare' => '<=',
    )
),
"meta_key"=>"price",
"orderby"=>"meta_value_num",
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

?>
```